# Detect closed Server-Sent Event clients in Jakarta EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, resteasy, server-sent-events, open-liberty

I'm trying to establish an SSE communication channel between a Jakarta EE server and other web or Java clients. In order to send messages to such clients, I keep a list of them as internal server state. The problem is, I can't find a way to detect when the clients close the connection, so that I can free up the corresponding server resources.

Here is more or less how I am establishing the connection:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/sse")
public class SseController {

    private Sse sse;
    private List<SseEventSink> sinks = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @GET
    @Produces(SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void onSse(@Context Sse sse, @Context SseEventSink sink) {
        this.sse = sse;
        this.sinks.add(sink);
    }
}
```

When is one supposed to clean up a closed client? From my tests, the server remains unaware of a client closure for as long as I've been willing to wait (~15 minutes), unless the server attempts to send *three* messages to the closed client; then somehow, after three send attempts, the third one fails, which gives an opportunity for cleaning up. I find this far from optimal.

If it helps, I am using OpenLiberty, which I believe uses RESTEasy as its SSE implementation.

Comment: What do you do with the sinks collection?

Comment: I later iterate through them and selectively send them messages (depending on the type of message each client/sink is interested on).

Comment: That seems like an odd use-case TBH. You could close them when the `SseController` is destroyed with a `@PreDestroy`, but it doesn't really sound like what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't see what's odd about sending messages to SSE clients... 
And no, you are right, `@PreDestroy` is not what I'm after.

Comment: What seems strange about it to me is collecting the `SseEventSink`. It's designed to be used with try-with-resources and disposed quickly.

Comment: Seriously? The server receives events and wants to relay them to some (or even all) clients. How's that not a use case considered in the design? That'd be baffling. I swear, Java sometimes...

Comment: I think you'd want to use a [`SseBroadcaster`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.1.html#sse_broadcasting) for that.

Comment: Except in my case I do want to be selective, as not all clients should receive all messages. In any case, for lack of better options, I indeed tried using `SseBroadcaster`, seeing that it has an `onClose()` callback. Unfortunately, it has the same limitation: a call to `SseEventSource.close()` by an SSE client does not trigger this callback, so the broadcaster continues to attempt sending messages long after the client has said bye-bye. It is only after three failed attempts that `onClose()` is called; and unless that happens, the clients keep accumulating in memory.

Comment: I'll see if I can create a reproducer. IIRC I've seen something similar with socket writes as there is no real way to know that client has been closed.

Comment: Regarding there not being a "real way to know that client has been closed", with the recent TCP standard consolidation into a single document, it might a good time to review this assumption. It seems clear to me that the standard does consider a sequence for peers to indicate they want to close a connection: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9293#name-closing-a-connection

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean by spec. I meant with socets/io/nio in Java.

Comment: Hi, DanielM and James, I have a very similar requirement. However, we're using Quarkus with RESTEasy and it seems to work as expected (?). I tried: register (store) SseEventSink -> close browser tab that had the EventSource bound -> check _.isClosed()_ and it returns true. I periodically clean up the sinks for which _.isClosed()_ is true. Any chance I might get memory leaks somewhere along the way?

Comment: I have no experience with Quarkus but, while your report is positively surprising, there seem to be a couple of open/closed-yet-unsolved issues that hint to them suffering from the same problems as Open Liberty: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8858, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32352. I encourage you to let them know if you somehow managed to get to a working solution.

Comment: You are right, I retested with RESTEasy Classic (+ quarkus-undertow as dependency): calling `.close()` on the UI `EventSource`, then check the corresponding sink `.isClosed()` on the back-end and it incorrectly says _false_. With RESTEasy Reactive, `.isClosed()` correctly equals _true_ after calling `.close()` on the UI `EventSource`.

Comment: I played around a bit more with the SseEventSink on Quarkus with RESTEasy Classic and it seems to me that when the sink is closed on the client side (either via `.close()` on EventSource or closing the browser tab), the `CompletionStage` from the SseEventSink's `.send(e)` never completes. Neither the `.whenComplete(...)` nor `.exceptionally(...)` callbacks are executed (even though the docs mention _If there is a problem during sending of an event, completion stage will be completed exceptionally._; needless to say, `.isClosed()` is always `false`). 1/2

Comment: To further test, I did `CompletableFuture<?> cf = sink.send(sse.newEvent("alive?")).toCompletableFuture();
cf.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` which unsurprisingly results in a TimeoutException after 5 seconds for the closed sinks (completes succesfully for the sinks that are actually open). To me, this looks like resources leak if the server tries to send events to closed sinks (which it believes are still open).

Comment: Also, I see you mentioned that your RESTEasy implementation detects that the sink is closed after the 3rd failed attempt and I started looking into the libraries and in RESTEasy's `SseEventOutputImpl` `.send(...)` there's this weird logic with an AtomicInteger where `state == 3` means "sink closed": `public CompletionStage<?> send(OutboundSseEvent event) {
        int state = this.state.get();
        if (state == 3) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(Messages.MESSAGES.sseEventSinkIsClosed());
} [...]` (_state_ is the AtomicInteger)  really messed up, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check if the stream has been closed via the isClosed() method documented in the javadoc for SseEventSink.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. After a client closes the connection (i.e. there is a call to `SseEventSource.close()`, after which `SseEventSource.isOpen()` correctly returns false), the server doesn't see that the connection has been closed (i.e. `SseEventSink.isClosed()` returns false). It is only after the server attempts and fails to send three messages to a closed client that `SseEventSink.send()` will return an exception, and from that point on `SseEventSink.isClosed()` correctly returns true.